# Why does a shell variable become an environment variable when it prefixes a command?

Tags: bash, shell

If I type the following command in a bash shell:

```
STUFF=Blah env | grep STUFF
```

I am confused why it would return `STUFF=Blah` as I would expect to get an empty output.

The reason I am confused is because (as I understand) `STUFF=Blah` sets STUFF as a *shell* variable, but the `env` command returns all *environment* variables.

But in the above `STUFF=Blah` seems to be set as an environment variable. Where am I going wrong in my understanding?

Answer (score 5):

From the bash man page (ENVIRONMENT section):

> The environment for any simple command or function may be augmented temporarily by prefixing it with parameter assignments, as described above in PARAMETERS.  These  assignment  statements  affect  only  the environment seen by that command.

This means that your understanding of the `STUFF=Blah` at the start of a command is incorrect. When using before a command, it sets an environment variable for the command being run. When used by itself (just `STUFF=Blah` without any further command), then it sets a local shell variable.

Comment: And because it only affects the immediately following command, it wouldn't be useful for it to set a shell variable.

Answer (score 4):

Prefixing a command with a variable assignment causes that command to run in an environment where that variable is set. The `env` command sees `STUFF` set to `Blah` in its environment, but not the current shell.

It's roughly equivalent to

```
(export STUFF=Blah; env | grep STUFF)
```

in that the assignment to `STUFF` does not affect the current shell, only `env`. (I say "roughly", because in this example `STUFF` is in the environment of every command executed in the subshell, not just `env`.)